# When is my code auto GPL'ed?

Tags: licensing, gpl

I'm currently working with Wordpress (GPL).
I understood basically when you write a plugin/module/etc. it becomes GPL since it's considered dependent of Wordpress.

But on the contrary images and css from themes, are not due to be GPL (they are considered independent data files that could have meaning even without Wordpress)

And that just blurs things a little bit for me.

What if I create a mathematical library non GPL. Then I create a Wordpress plugin that use that library?

Will it makes my library GPL? Would it means I cannot bundle them together? Not even put them on a single zip file?

What if my library is a Web service? And what if the web service is self hosted? May I bundle it with the plugin code altogether?

If I can't make any kind of bundle without GPL being propagated, how comes one can bundle a theme (feat. css + images) for Wordpress?

Answer (score 4):

When you create a plugin for a product that uses the GPL license, then the plugin itself and any libraries that the plugin uses *do not* need to use the GPL license themselves.

However, you are not entirely free in your choice of license. As the GPL terms apply to the entire product and spread out to all plugins as well, your plugin and all the libraries it depends on must use a license that is *compatible with* the GPL. The easiest way to be compatible is to use the same license, but most popular open-source licenses are compatible.

What this means for the concrete example you give, if your mathematical library uses a compatible open-source license (for example, the MIT license), then there is no problem with using it in a Wordpress plugin and you can distribute it together with that plugin.

When it comes to completely unrelated programs, you can always combine those in a distribution without having the copyright licenses affect each other. In legal terms this is called "Mere Aggregation" and allows you even to distribute Wordpress with unrelated commercial (closed source) programs as long as they are completely independent of each other.
If themes are legally considered to be independent of Wordpress, then they can be distributed alongside Wordpress itself, even when they have incompatible licenses, under the principle of Mere Aggregation.

Comment: So, how do I get my (fictional*) mathematical library not to be open source and yet be used by the plugin? *I'm far from mathematic savvy.

Comment: @Serge: That won't be possible, as non-open source licenses are not compatible with the GPL.

Comment: Then I don't get how images/css don't need to be open source while used on a theme.

Comment: @Serge: The GPL claims that its terms apply to all code that executes in the same process as the GPL code. Images and CSS don't get executed by the process that runs the Wordpress software (if you can say they get executed at all), so for that reason they don't fall under the GPL terms

Comment: @Bart: Since the math library is presumably usable on its own and therefore an independent piece of software, it's not automatically also covered by the GPL. They'll just have to be distributed as separate pieces. Also hi from 3 zuid :-)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: If the math library is linked to a GPL plugin (or, going by the FSF interpretation, a plugin to a GPL program), then the GPL requirements of source availability and right to modify also extend to the math library, regardless of its license. If the license of the math library doesn't give you the same freedoms as the GPL, then you can't legally distribute the result.

Comment: I realize that after linking the resulting program can't be legally distributed. But you can distribute library and plugin separately under different licenses, and then let the customer do the "linking" (not much linking in PHP code).

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: If the plugin refers to the library, then I am not convinced that such separate distribution will hold up in court. But then again, it might.

Comment: Consider the case where the library is completely third party. Surely there can be GPL software that talks to closed source libraries? E.g. open source software on Windows doing system calls.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: With GPLv2 this is unclear. With GPLv3, the implementations of standard interfaces and the major OS components are explicitly exempt from the GPL requirements.